# PDFBox:Deep clone specific resources from page (ColorSpaces)

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a use case where I need to deep clone specific resource (ColorSpaces only), I don't want to deep clone the entire resources for several reasons, I want to shallow copy resources but deep clone colorspaces only, is this possible? I tried to deep clone the color spaces, but it didn't work well, but it has problems

I tried to shallow copy the resources into the xobject, and deep clone the colorspaces, but that didn't work

```
            PDFormXObject xobject = new PDFormXObject(target);
            InputStream in = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            if (page.hasContents()) {
                try {
                    in = page.getContents();
                    os = xobject.getStream().createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
                    IOUtils.copy(in, os);
                } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
                    IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);
                }
                xobject.setResources(page.getResources());
                ArrayList<PDSeparation> set = new ArrayList<PDSeparation>();
                    for (COSName colorSpaceName : page.getResources().getColorSpaceNames()) {
                        PDColor spotColor = page.getResources().getColorSpace(colorSpaceName).getInitialColor();
                        if (spotColor.getColorSpace() != null && spotColor.getColorSpace() instanceof PDSeparation) {
                            PDSeparation SeparationColorSpace = (PDSeparation) spotColor.getColorSpace();
                            COSArray arr = (COSArray) cloneForNewDocument(SeparationColorSpace.getCOSObject());
                            xobject.getResources().add(new PDSeparation(arr));
                        }
                    }
```

Is it possible to deep clone the colorspaces from the page, and shallow copy the rest of the resources?

Comment: How do you know "that didn't work"? Please clarify - what happens? What should have happened? The clone class isn't meant to be used outside of PDFBox (see class javadoc) but it should work. What your current code is doing is to add a second copy of that colorspace in the resources, that looks ok to me. I also don't understand why you're using initialcolor. It doesn't hurt, but it uses the same colorspace.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr my case is: I have a 100 page pdf, each page contain the SAME xobject but with different colors, the problem is the output has the size of almost 300MB, if I do xobject.setResources(page.getResource())I will end up having the same colors for all xobjects (since I do not close neither the target document nor the original document - page - . I tried to set the colorspaces on page level (pageout which holds the xobject) lby changing the last two lines:  see next comment

Comment: Cont. 
PDSeparation SeparationColorSpace = (PDSeparation) spotColor.getColorSpace();
   pageOut.getResources().put(colorSpaceName, SeparationColorSpace);
I get output pdf with different colors on each page, and output result is 1.7MB.
P.S: I agree on the usage on initialColor, it is not necessary in this case

Comment: I still don't follow you - if you got the file from 300MB down to 1.7MB then your problem is solved, isn't it? Btw if it is the same object, then construct it only once.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr yes, I played with the code and it worked eventually, but I don't know why, why when I add the color spaces on the xobject level at each page the size goes very high, while adding the colorspaces at page level the output size is very small

Comment: I can't tell, you should delete this one and create a new question that has both code variations and also share the PDF. But likely it is related to whether it is all the same object or a new object each time.